# Popup is not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, popup

After clicking on `btn1` the classes (`popup-open` for popup div and `popup-form` for form div) are added to class list.

I am trying to display a "THANK YOU" message after the form is submitted. When the submit button is clicked, it will trigger the popup. My popup is displaying only for less than 1 seconds and automatically hides afterwards.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Space;
  src: url(https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Space+Grotesk);
}

body {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#side {
  height: 670px;
}

.cardfront {
  color: white;
  background-image: url(images/bg-card-front.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
  top: -585px;
  left: 129px;
  height: 230px;
}

.cardfront img {
  margin: 16px;
}

.cardfront p {
  position: relative;
  left: 31px;
  font-size: 35px;
  top: 19px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.cardfront div {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.cardfront div span:first-child {
  margin-left: 14px;
  margin-right: 212px;
}

.cardback {
  background-image: url(images/bg-card-back.png);
  width: 467px;
  height: 305px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: -560px;
  left: 260px;
  position: relative;
}

.cardback p {
  position: relative;
  left: 354px;
  top: 107px;
  font-size: 26px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

form {
  font-weight: 500;
}

#Name,
#cardNumber {
  width: 332px;
  height: 39px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #ddd0d0;
  margin-top: -10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

form div input {
  height: 57px;
  width: 73px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #ddd0d0;
  margin-top: -8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#cvc {
  width: 124px;
  margin-right: -17px;
}

form #row div {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#btn {
  width: 351px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: larger;
  color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: #060e1e;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-top: 24px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#btn:active,
#btn:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(219deg, #461d81, #121112ed);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
}

.form {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.popup {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -467px;
  left: 27%;
  transition: 2s;
}

.thnks {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.msg2 {
  color: #666262;
}

#btn2 {
  width: 351px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: larger;
  color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: #060e1e;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#btn2:active,
#btn2:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(219deg, #461d81, #121112ed);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup-open {
  visibility: visible;
}

.popup-form {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add all relevant code to the question

Comment: If you change the `transition` to `transition:2s`, does the popup show longer? 

Comment: no, it is not affected by the transition property.

Comment: Are you submitting the form to another page? That would render the popup moot - and explain why it's automatically removed.

Comment: no, the form is enclosed within a div with class name "form" in the same html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using a form and a submit button like

```
 <form>
   <button type="submit">
</form>
```

then the problem is when u submit any form it reload the window automatically it is the default behaviour of the form.
so this will reset all the content on the page.
**You can prevent this default behaviour by using " onsubmit="return false;" this event like in the code below**

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" >
   <button type="submit">
</form>
```

If even now your problem is not resolving then please give some more details about the code (eg, code of html, javascript file).